Why does my code not recognize the module "pybricks"?
I am using Visual Studio and I am coding with Python
My Output result:
Starting: brickrun --directory="/home/robot/ColorSensor" "/home/robot/ColorSensor/main.py"
Starting program failed: Failed to execute child process "/home/robot/ColorSensor/main.py" (Permission denied)
Exited with error code 1.
My Terminal result:
PS C:\Users\Student_CSE\Downloads\ColorSensor> & c:/Users/Student_CSE/Downloads/ColorSensor/.venv/Scripts/python.exe c:/Users/Student_CSE/Downloads/ColorSensor/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\Student_CSE\Downloads\ColorSensor\main.py", line 1, in 
from pybricks.hubs import EV3Brick
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pybricks'
My goal is to make my EV3 recognize a color and then do a task depending on the color recognized, I believe the code works.
The code:
    from pybricks.hubs import EV3Brick
    from pybricks.ev3devices import (Motor, TouchSensor, ColorSensor,
                                 InfraredSensor, UltrasonicSensor, GyroSensor)
    from pybricks.parameters import Port, Stop, Direction, Button, Color
    from pybricks.tools import wait, StopWatch, DataLog
    from pybricks.robotics import DriveBase
    from pybricks.media.ev3dev import SoundFile, ImageFile

    ev3 = EV3Brick()
    robot = DriveBase(left_motor, right_motor, wheel_diameter=55.5, axle_track=104)
    left_motor = Motor(Port.B)
    right_motor = Motor(Port.C)
    color_sensor = ColorSensor(Port.S1)
    POSSIBLE_COLORS = [Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE]
    color = color_sensor.color()

    if Color == Color.BLACK:
        robot.turn(180)
        ev3.speaker.beep()
    else: Color == Color.WHITE
    robot.turn(-180)
    ev3.speaker.beep()

Every time the code just doesn't work, I have uninstalled python and the ev3 extension and then reinstalled it. I also closed and reopen Visual studio multiple times and I can't find anything online that works.

Pybricks is a progressive web app as seen here. While it can be downloaded and used offline as an application, the optimal way would be to use the web-based version.
If you do want to program locally with it though there is an "Install as app" button in the second page I linked.
